# How to linebreak when using \rotatebox inside a tikz node?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to know how I can get a linebreak inside a rotated node using tikz. I tried to use the `align=center` option together with `\rotatebox{}{}`, but i get an error. Here is an example of a working code but without the linebreak:

```
\begin{figure}[h!tp]
\begin{tikzpicture}[generaloptions/.style 2 args={
draw,ultra thick,font={\bfseries},inner sep=0,outer sep=0,minimum height=#1,minimum width=#2}]
\node[generaloptions={3.5cm}{1.5cm},align=center,anchor=south west,font=\footnotesize\bfseries] (l1) at ([xshift=-1.5cm]big.south west) {\rotatebox{90}{Line Break}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

I would like something like this but instead i get an error:

```
\begin{figure}[h!tp]
\begin{tikzpicture}[generaloptions/.style 2 args={
 draw,ultra thick,font={\bfseries},inner sep=0,outer sep=0,minimum height=#1,minimum width=#2}]
 \node[generaloptions={3.5cm}{1.5cm},align=center,anchor=south west,font=\footnotesize\bfseries] (l1) at ([xshift=-1.5cm]big.south west) {\rotatebox{90}{Line \\ Break}};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure}
```

I am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rotatebox` tries to rotate every thing inside as if it were a box. Hence you can't expect a line break. You may put the content inside a `parbox`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[generaloptions/.style 2 args={
 draw,ultra thick,font={\bfseries},inner sep=0,outer sep=0,minimum height=#1,minimum width=#2}]
 \node[generaloptions={3.5cm}{1.5cm},align=center,anchor=south west,font=\footnotesize\bfseries] (l1) at (0,0) {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox[c]{1.5cm}{\centering Line  Break}}};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to rotate the text alone and have line break, you may use the option `rotate=90,text width = 1.5cm` (and ditch the `rotatebox`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[generaloptions/.style 2 args={
 draw,ultra thick,font={\bfseries},inner sep=0,outer sep=0,minimum height=#1,minimum width=#2}]
 \node[generaloptions={1.5cm}{3.5cm},text width = 1.5cm,align=center,anchor=south west,font=\footnotesize\bfseries,rotate=90] (l1) at (0,0) {Line  Break and break yes };
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may have to interchange the `minimum height` and `minimum width` though.

Comment: @jon86 Welcome :-)