# How to add a linebreak in a pgf-umlsd UML Sequence Diagram instance/thread

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-breaking, pgf-umlsd

I'm writing a UML sequence diagram with tikz package `pgf-umlsd`. Currently the code looks as follows:

```
\begin{sequencediagram}
    \newthread{controller}{Special Task Controller}
    \newinst{servicea}{Service A}
    \newinst{serviceb}{Service B}
    \newinst{servicec}{Service C}

    \begin{call}{controller}{HTTP GET /}{servicea}{}
    \end{call}
    \begin{call}{controller}{HTTP GET /}{serviceb}{}
    \end{call}
    \begin{call}{controller}{HTTP GET /}{servicec}{}
    \end{call}
\end{sequencediagram}
```

My problem is, that it has to be embedded in a two-column document, where one column isn't very wide and I'd like to save some space by wrapping the threads name `Special Task Controller` in the box. Is there any way of adding a line break in there?

(Making the sequence diagram go over two columns is not an option, since it will not be wide enough to fill the complete with of the page)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer here: [How to linebreak when using \rotatebox inside a tikz node?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93878/how-to-linebreak-when-using-rotatebox-inside-a-tikz-node)

You have to define a `\parbox` as title, which has the desired width:

```
\parbox[c]{1.5cm}{\centering Line  Break}
```

alternatively is is possible to use the command `\shortstack{}`, where `\\`-linebreaks will work.

```
\shortstack{Line\\ Break}
```

which would look as follows in the `\newthread` command

```
\newthread{controller}{\parbox[c]{1.5cm}{\centering Special Task Controller}}
```

resp.

```
\newthread{controller}{\shortstack{Special Task\\ Controller}}
```

(Simply `\\`, `\linebreak` or `\linebreak{}` doesn't work.)