# Line break in TikZ-UML state transition

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-uml

Let's take a look at the following example state diagram created with TikZ-UML:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \umlstateinitial[name=initial]

        \begin{umlstate}[name=simple,below=30mm of initial]{Simple state}

        \end{umlstate}

        \umltrans[arg={This is a very very very long text},pos=0.5]{initial}{simple}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

My question: How can I insert a line break in the long arg description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `text width` to some reasonable value.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \umlstateinitial[name=initial]

        \begin{umlstate}[name=simple,below=30mm of initial]{Simple state}

        \end{umlstate}

        \umltrans[arg={This is a very very very long text},pos=0.5,text width=2cm]{initial}{simple}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know a similiar way to split the state title `Simple state` into multiple lines?

Comment: @Marcello90 Sorry, no. I'd suggest asking a new question about that.

Comment: @Marcello90 There is no `text width` option available, so it seems that you'll have to use a `\parbox` or a `tabular` to break the umlstate title.

Comment: @Marcello90 [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/288591) might help.